# How do I embed a dreemgl widget outside the server framework?

Tags: dreemgl

I'd like to use the DreemGL framework (in particular the widgets, a very nice set of GL widgets) in my frontend code, but I'd rather not use the backend server pieces. How can I embed and use just the widgets, without using the server on the backend? Is there any example of this?

Answer (score 0):

That's currently not possible with DreemGL. You can only run compositions with the backend server active.